# Can't access Motorola Milestone on Ubuntu 9.10 via adb (HTC Magic works perfectly fine)

Tags: android, hardware, usb, motorola, milestone

I've two phones, the HTC Magic and since today also the Motorola
Milestone.

While the Magic works perfectly, I'm not able to access the Milestone
via USB (adb devices).

Here are my log outputs and settings for both:

**HTC Magic**

**lsusb:**

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bb4:0c02 High Tech Computer Corp.
```

**/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules:**

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
```

**/var/log/messages**

```
Jan 12 20:05:44 ubuntu kernel: [  764.343311] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HTC      Android Phone    0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jan 12 20:05:44 ubuntu kernel: [  764.343826] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jan 12 20:05:44 ubuntu kernel: [  764.353414] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

---

**Motorola Milestone**

**lsusb:**

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 22b8:41da Motorola PCS
```

**/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules:**

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"
```

**/var/log/messages**

```
Jan 12 20:10:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 1028.580017] usb 1-3: new high speed
USB device using ehci_hcd and address 11
Jan 12 20:10:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 1028.731068] usb 1-3: configuration
#1 chosen from 1 choice
```

---

**Notes**

- USB Debugging is enabled on both phones
- After changing the udev rules I did a "service udev reload" and
  "adb kill-server" -> didn't help
- I even tried to restart the whole machine. Without success.

Anyone encountered a similar problem and had a solution?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you running, and can you mount the SD card from the device over USB?

Comment: Yes, make sure to get the latest SDK tools (including adb), as the old tools bundled with the 1.6 SDK will not see 2.0+ devices.

Comment: I already completely reinstalled the SDK, but that didn't help. I finally found the solution. See my answer below. Thanks for your hints, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, as usual, simpler than expected. Even though **USB debugging** is enabled you additional have to pull down the *notification bar* and go to **USB connection**.

There you have 4 options:

- Motorola Phone Tools
- Windows Media Sync
- Memory Card Management
- None

Here you have to select **"None"**

After that everything works fine.

Comment: And what about Android 2.3.6, wich doesn't have those options? It has only "activate/deactivate usb storage" and both does not work!!

Answer (score 1):

I actually ***had*** to use the "Memory Card Management" option for it to work on Ubuntu 8.10. In "None" mode it would not mount.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for some newer phones, rather than selecting **None**, **PC Mode** might also work as well. I spent a good 45 minutes trying to get this to work when all I had to do was set it to that.

**Note**

This is on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.